# CircularProgressIndicator in flutter keeps spinning

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to place my CircularProgressIndicator when my flutter app is fetching the PDF from my firebase. But, the weird part is it does not show the CircularProgressIndicator when the button is press to open PDF instead it shows TOGETHER (AT THE SAME TIME) when PDF is loaded which defeats the purpose as I want it to show when it is loading not appearing same time as PDF.

2nd weird thing is, my CircularProgressIndicator keeps on spinning even after PDF is displayed.

Video demo:
[image]

My code (PDF VIEWER PAGE):

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_pdfview/flutter_pdfview.dart';
import 'package:flutter_web_browser/flutter_web_browser.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'dart:async';

openBrowserTab() async {
  await FlutterWebBrowser.openWebPage(
      url:
          "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScdrUJaGxFCLSJV7Njg8WZlqLZOh40Jq000hggexoRjA1-8nQ/viewform?usp=sf_link",
      customTabsOptions: CustomTabsOptions(
        toolbarColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      ));
}

class PDFViewerPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final File file;

  const PDFViewerPage({
    Key? key,
    required this.file,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PDFViewerPageState createState() => _PDFViewerPageState();
}


class _PDFViewerPageState extends State<PDFViewerPage> {
  bool isReady = false;
final Completer<PDFViewController> _controller = Completer<PDFViewController>();
  String errorMessage = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final name = basename(widget.file.path);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(name),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.error,
              color: Colors.yellow,
            ),
            onPressed: () => openBrowserTab(),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          PDFView(
            pageSnap: false,
            pageFling: false,
            autoSpacing: false,
            filePath: widget.file.path,
            onRender: (_pages) {
              setState(() {
                isReady = true;
              });
            },
            onError: (error) {
              setState(() {
                errorMessage = error.toString();
              });
              print(error.toString());
            },
            onPageError: (page, error) {
              setState(() {
                errorMessage = '$page: ${error.toString()}';
              });
              print('$page: ${error.toString()}');
            },
              onViewCreated: (PDFViewController pdfViewController) {
              _controller.complete(pdfViewController);
            },
          ),
          errorMessage.isEmpty
              ? !isReady
                  ? Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    )
                  : Container()
              : Center(
                  child: Text('Please check your internet connection'),
                ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Additional information: I am using this package to view PDF. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pdfview/example

Hope to get some guidance from you guys. Thank you!

Comment: Where do you change the value of `isReady` variable ?

Comment: Hi buddy! Where should I set isReady to true and where to false?

Comment: You create it as `false` which makes sense but you need to change it when the file is loaded, you check against `false` thats why spinner never leaves. Is there any `onReady` function to change ti value inside it ?

Comment: Okay I added the onRender and setState to true but how the ciruclarprogressindicator is not showing though

Answer (score 1):

add this code under the `pdfView`, you need to change the value of `isReady` when page render done.

```
onRender: (_pages) {
              setState(() {
                isReady = true;
              });
            },
```

Comment: I added but how do I trigger circularprogressindicator as it is not showing?

Comment: you can add `PDFViewController`; hope to solve it.

Comment: you mean add this
```onViewCreated: (PDFViewController pdfViewController) {
    _controller.complete(pdfViewController);
  },```
?

Comment: yeah you can try with this

Comment: hmm can you show me a sample code on adding ```PDFViewController?```

The one i showed was from the package but there's error using it

Comment: add this line ` final Completer<PDFViewController> _controller =
      Completer<PDFViewController>();` in `_PDFViewerPageState `

Comment: Okay, but how to define class completor since its undefined class?

Comment: `import 'dart:async';` this line

Comment: Oh man, i added, no errors, idk why but its still not showing, okay I have updated latest code in the question with the pdfviewcontroller